# converting ui file into py using pyside6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside6

I just try pyside6 to convert ui files into py files.

When I was using pyside2, I was writing this commande line to convert file:

```
pyside2-uic MainWindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.py -x
```

But with pyside6, it is not working anymore: the "-x" doesn't look necessary. So you have to write:

```
pyside6-uic MainWindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.py
```

BUT, when I run the new file generated, nothing happend. I had a look at the end of file, and it is missing a part there was with pyside2. This part of code is not here anymore:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: what is the meaning of *But with pyside6, it is not working anymore: the "-x" doesn't look necessary*?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is import the class the uic created:

```
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
```

Then I create a QMainWindow class and instantiate the uic class.
You need to call the setupUi method on the instance.

```
class UI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = UI()
    win.show()
    app.exec()
```

Now, you can access all the widgets via self.ui:

```
self.ui.myPushButton.clicked.connect(self.doSomething)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong, that part of the code is added to create an "executable" version of the pyuic file, and its purpose is mainly to *test* it.

I don't know if the support for `-x` has been dropped, but that makes sense, and it won't matter a lot anyway: pyuic generated files are not intended to be executed, and should *not* ***ever*** be manually modified, since they should only be used as imports as explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/designer.html#using-the-generated-code).

Comment: Thank you !! I understand now. it is more clear now